# Import monads doesnt work (leaking haskell platform)

Tags: haskell, import, monads, haskell-platform

As there is no haskell-plattform for the newest Ubuntu 13.04, I only downloaded the GHCi and had no problems until now.

But now I want to work with monads. Importing them with

```
import Control.Monad.State
```

for example does not work. The error message:

```
Could not find module `Control.Monad.State'
Perhaps you meant
  Control.Monad.ST (from base)
  Control.Monad.ST.Safe (from base)
  Control.Monad.Fix (from base)
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How can I manually download them, or is there an entirely different problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to install the library somewhere GHC can find it.

## Installing via Cabal

### Install Cabal

If you haven't installed `cabal-install`  then do that first.  Do this one of two ways.

Via OS Packaging:

```
sudo apt-get install cabal-install
```

or manually:

```
wget http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install-1.18.0.2/cabal-install-1.18.0.2.tar.gz
tar xzf cabal-install-1.18.0.2.tar.gz
cd cabal-install-1.18.0.2
sh ./bootstrap.sh
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.cabal/bin
```

### Use Cabal

Once you have installed `cabal-install` then do:

```
cabal update
cabal install mtl
```

This is the "Monad Transformer Library" which includes many common monads, such as `State`, that you see used in examples.

## Install via OS Packaging

Alternative to all of this is to install the ubuntu packaging of `mtl`.  That said, I don't know any active Haskell developers who use OS packagings of Haskell packages instead of cabal.  The ubuntu package is `libghc-ghc-mtl-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libghc-ghc-mtl-dev
```

Comment: now he says: Not in scope: type constructor or class `State', same for Trans.State

Comment: @user2664856 What did you do? This answer is correct: `cabal install mtl`.

Comment: yes i did excatly this, and it worked properly, but the error keeps coming ... dont get me wrong, the error changed. i will edit my post to be more precise.

Comment: UPDATE: i created a new file and extracted the bits with monads, now it seems to work.  Thank you all ! now it works ... i just made a very stupid mistake (imported another monad than the one that is used) in the old code.

Comment: Glad it worked.  Now just don't get caught up thinking that MTL is the _only_ monad library.  There are others that some like even more (ex: monadlib).

Answer (score 1):

## Using Stack

If you're using [Stack](https://haskellstack.org), you can get the [monad transformer library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html) by adding `transformers` to the dependencies of your `package.yml`:

```
executables:
  state-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - state
    - transformers
```